# Showing that the spans of two sets of vectors are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector $v_k$ is a linear combination of vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{k-1}$. How do I prove that the span of set of vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{k-1}$ is equal to the span of set of vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ by containment?

Comment: My approach at this problem. I can easily show that Span{v1, v2,...vk} is the subset of Span {v1, v2, ....v(k-1)}. But I was confused how to do the other way round. Can I just do this?
Let's say a vector y belongs to span{v1,v2,....v(k-1)} which means y can be expressed as y=c1v1+.....+c(k-1)v(k-1) which can be rewritten as y=c1v1+....+c(k-1)v(k-1)+0.vk hence y belongs to span{v1,...vk}.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will mainly be an exercise in notation, but here goes...

Let $V=span \{ v_1, ~v_2 ,\dots, v_{k-1} \}$ and let $W=span \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$. Seek to show that $V=W$, so we need to show that $V \subseteq W$ and $W \subseteq V$.

Claim $V \subseteq W$:

- Let $v \in V$. Then $v= a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{k-1} v_{k-1} $. Then $v=  a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{k-1} v_{k-1} + 0 v_k$, so $v$ is in $W$.

Claim $W \subseteq V$:

- Since $v_k \in V = span \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{k-1} \}$, we have that $v_k = b_1 v_1 + b_2 v_2 + \cdots + b_{k-1} v_{k-1}$. Let $w \in W$ be given. Then \begin{align*}
  w&= c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_{k-1} v_{k-1} + c_k v_k  \\
   &= c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_{k-1} v_{k-1} + c_k (b_1 v_1 + b_2 v_2 + \cdots + b_{k-1} v_{k-1}) \\
   &= (c_1 + c_k b_1) v_1 + (c_2 + c_k b_2) v_2 + \cdots + (c_{k-1} + c_k b_{k-1}) v_{k-1}
  \end{align*}
  So $w \in span \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{k-1} \} = V$.

**Edit**

Note that this proof is relatively atrocious notation--waay too many characters and subscripts floating around, leading to a very bloated proof. A much more elegant proof can be given using summation notation ($\sum$) or with matrices. However, I am inferring that you are in an introductory linear algebra course, so I went with the "brute force" approach to highlight what is really going on, without getting to lost using fancy notation.

Answer (score 0):

If $(\lambda_j)$ are scalars, we wish to find $(\mu_j)$ such that
$$ \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \mu_j v_j
$$
Obseve that since $v_k$ is a linear combination of $(v_j)_{j=1}^{k-1}$, there exists scalars $(\nu_j)$ such that $v_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \nu_j v_j$. Therefore we can define $\mu_j = \lambda_j + \nu_j\lambda_k$. Then
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \mu_j v_j
= \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \lambda_j v_j + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \nu_j\lambda_k v_j = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \lambda_j v_j + \lambda_k v_k
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less a homework type question in almost every linear algebra book. You can start if off with setting $S = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1}\}$, and $T = S\cup \{v_k\}$. Thus $S \subseteq T\implies \text{span}{(S)}\subseteq \text{span(T)}$. Also $v_k \in \text{span(S)}\implies T \subseteq\text{span(S)}\implies \text{span(T)} \subseteq \text{span(S)}$. Thus:  $\text{span(S)} = \text{span(T)}$ as claimed.